# How can I shorten the massive calls of the same method?

Tags: java, random

I want to create a binary tree with random numbers. For that I have a function that generates the tree and a function that generates the random numbers. As instance variables i have following:

```
private static final int MIN_VALUE = 1;
private static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
private static LinkedBinaryTree<Integer> tree = new LinkedBinaryTree<>();
private static Random random = new Random();
```

I think it doesn't look "beautiful" with all the generateRandomInt calls. Is there a way to shorten this or make it more efficient? Is there also a way to create randomly a binary tree (number of nodes)? I have the methods following methods to add something to a tree:

```
addRoot(value)
insertLeftChild(node, value)
insertRightChild(node, value)
insertChild(node, value)
insertChildren(node, value1, value2)
```

**addRoot** adds a root node, **insertLeftChild** and **insertRightChild** add a left or right child to node, **insertChild** does the same, but it checks if left or right child is free, **insertChildren** adds a left and a right child at the same time to node

```
public static int generateRandomInt(int MIN_VALUE, int MAX_VALUE) {
        return random.nextInt((MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) + 1) + MIN_VALUE;
}
```

```
public static void generateBinaryTree() {
        Position<Integer> root = tree.addRoot(generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        Position<Integer> child1 = tree.insertChild(root, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        Position<Integer> child2 = tree.insertChild(root, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        Position<Integer> child3 = tree.insertChild(child1, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        Position<Integer> child4 = tree.insertChild(child1, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        Position<Integer> child5 = tree.insertChild(child2, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        Position<Integer> child6 = tree.insertChild(child2, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        tree.insertChildren(child3, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE), generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        tree.insertChildren(child4, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE), generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        tree.insertChildren(child5, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE), generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));
        tree.insertChildren(child6, generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE), generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE));      
    }
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `insertChild` and `insertChildren` or is that some sort of copy-paste error?

Comment: And unrelated: it is perfectly fair to have those two **constants** MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE. But it is very wrong to name your method parameters **the same**. Your method should go `... generateRandomIntInRange(int min, int max)`. By using the very same names that you already have in place you open up a can of problems!

Comment: @tobias_k Yes there is a difference. insertChildren adds a left and a right child to a node at the same time. insertChild inserts one child (right or left child) to a node.

Comment: So, `insertChildren` is basically just two calls to `insertChild`? In this case, you might indeed make some recursive function `buildTree(int depth)` to do all this for you.

Comment: @tobias_k insertChildren calls insertLeft and insertRight. Those methods are from an given interface. I have implemented it by using insertLeft and insertRight. But you are right, it would also work with two insertChild calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do away with passing the `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` everywhere, as it is the same, so you can remove the parameters from your function (Or create a proxy).

But you will not be able to have less call, as the result can not be cached.

What you can do to "embellish" your code is to use a terminal recursive function.
Something like :

```
public static void addChild(int depth, Position<Integer>  currentRoot) {
    Position<Integer> leftChild = currentRoot.insertLeftChild(generateRandomInt());
    Position<Integer> rightChild = currentRoot.insertRightChild(generateRandomInt());
    if(depth > 0) {
        addChild(depth - 1, leftChild);
        addChild(depth - 1, rightChild);
    }
}
```

You might have to edit your `insertChild()` method to return the inserted node.

*EDIT:* Call methods twice to get binary tree.

Comment: Just what I thoght after reading OP's comment about `addChildren`, but I think you should call `addChild` _twice_ recursively to get a binary tree.

Comment: @tobias_k you are right, I did not dig into the implementation details, I just wanted to expose the general idea of using recursion. I'll edit to use `addChildren()` then.

Comment: @Kevin FONTAINE thank you very much for sharing your idea

Answer (score 3):

Simple add another helper, like:

```
public static int generateRandomInt() {
  return generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Next you could create helper methods that simply create a child and add it to a root. To then call that method within a loop.

Basically you have a pattern here:

- you create Position objects (whatever those are, shouldn't they be called *Node*?)
- you add these positions into your tree

All of that happens on a very low abstraction level. You should add some helpful abstractions that remove the need to always always write down all the details.

Comment: Actually, I would suggest calling the function `generateRandomInt` as well, to make more clear that it is a parameter-less version of the same function.

Comment: @tobias_k Good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what [@GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56077272/1639625) suggested, but instead of defining another function, you could also just define a `Supplier<Integer>` within the scope of your method. Especially if the parameters to the random function are not always the same (maybe different bounds when used in another method) this may be advantageous.
Also, it is again a bit shorter, as the locally declared `Supplier` does not have to have an overly descriptive name.

```
public static void generateBinaryTree() {
    Supplier<Integer> rand = () -> generateRandomInt(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);

    Position<Integer> root = tree.addRoot(rand.get());
    Position<Integer> child1 = tree.insertChild(root, rand.get());
    ...
}
```

*Update:* After understanding the difference between `addChild` and `addChildren`, it is clear that you can indeed rewrite your function in a recursive manner as `addChildren(root, depth)` as suggested by [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56077398/1639625).